# Firefox session not deleting automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cookies

I'm running Linux Mint and using Firefox 3.6.10. I'm setting a cookie using jQuery

```
$.cookie("ws", "1") ;
```

This cookie will expires At end of session. But when I close the browser. This session is not expiring automatically. Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem. It happens when you set up your browser to remember opened tabs. In this case firefox does not delete session cookies, since the session didn't ended, and will continue when browser is opened again